# PL/SQL: Join statements in for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a beginner in PL/SQL.

I am trying to loop through every months in a specific dataframe, select a couple of attributes for each user and append it (join) into a table where each row represents one user. I am very open for alternative (possibly faster), completely different sollutions.

```
BEGIN
      ResultTable = ???
    FOR k IN 1..24 LOOP
      SELECT * FROM(
         SELECT a.Userid, a.size as ('size, time=' || to_char(k)), a.weight as ('weight, time=' || to_char(k))
            FROM Original a
            INNER JOIN ResultTable b
               ON a.Userid= b.Userid
       ) ResultTable 
    END LOOP;  
    END;
```

For example:

```
+--------+------+------+--------+----+
|   ID   | time | size | weight | …  |
+--------+------+------+--------+----+
| 1      | 1    | 4    | 5      | .. |
| 1      | 2    | 6    | 11     | .. |
| 1      | …    | ..   | ..     | .. |
| 1      | 24   | 8    | 3      | .. |
| 2      | 1    | 4    | 5      | .. |
| 2      | 2    | 8    | 11     | .. |
| 2      | …    | ..   | ..     | .. |
| 2      | 24   | 18   | 5      | .. |
| …      | …    | …    | …      | …  |
| 278000 | 1    | 8    | 6      | .. |
| 278000 | 2    | 16   | 11     | .. |
| 278000 | …    | ..   | ..     | .. |
| 278000 | 24   | 8    | 3      | .. |
+--------+------+------+--------+----+


+--------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---+--------+----------+
|   ID   | size1  | weight1 | size2 | weight2 | … | size24 | weight24 |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---+--------+----------+
| 1      | 4      | 5       | 6     | 11      | … | 8      | 3        |
| 2      | 4      | 5       | 8     | 11      | … | 18     | 5        |
| …      | …      | …       | …     | …       | … | …      | …        |
| 278000 | 8      | 6       | 16    | 11      | … | 8      | 3        |
+--------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---+--------+----------+
```

I have edited my question to make it more readable.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the table/data as text - not all of us can see images (firewall) and it's easier for us to copy text than having to write it out ourselves - please help us to help you by making it easy for us.

Comment: What version is the database you are using? (`SELECT VERSION FROM v$instance;`)

Comment: I use:12.1.0.2.0

Comment: I guess this can be easily achieved by using PIVOT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` as following:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ID, TIME, SIZE, WEIGHT FROM YOUR_TABLE
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX(SIZE) AS SIZE, MAX(WEIGHT) AS WEIGHT 
  FOR TIME IN (1,2,3,...24)
)
```

Cheers!!